# "Tags" vs "Labels"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

The word "Tags" is all well and good for the current inhabitants of Stack Exchange Land, but in the future, when more and more users join, I think that the term may end up sounding confusing to newbies.

I propose that the tagging interface should be titled:

**Labels / Tags**

To reduce the amount of noise, once the site is out of beta.

Comment: I think this should be asked in a more general meta, as this is not confined to gaming alone.

Comment: -1, It's a convention across the SO/SE sites. Why change now?

Answer (score 8):

I think the concept of "tags" is pretty widely used these days.

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely we will change this on a per-site basis as it'd cause confusion.